# Can I make SharePoint 13 home page only viewable to me?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

We are running a SharePoint 2013 test site in order to learn the application. 
I went to **Home**... **selected the gear on the upper right side**... selected **Edit Page**... selected **Insert** and added Blog Tools, My Libraries, About this Community and my Page to the page. Everyone who is using this SharePoint test site can see these additions. My question is, is there a way for me to make these inserts only viewable to me?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can audience a web part to a particular group, that web part would only then be viewable by that particular user. See URL for more information; 
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Introduction-to-targeting-content-on-a-SharePoint-site-to-specific-audiences-3009b54d-c157-4d85-ae1f-18a974b63524

Comment: Thanks. I'll read  the link. I just learned how to create a sub-site. I can always insert the information to my sub-site as well.